# Securing Azure HTTP Functions using Okta or other bearer tokens

Tags: angular, azure-functions, serverless, okta

I am using Azure HTTP serverless functions that are being called from SPA applications using bearer tokens.  Is it possible to implement that type of security on HTTP serverless functions to use bearer token to secure the endpoints?  TIA

Looked at various OOB function security

Looked at some home-grown solutions that check for a token in header, but that does not leverage the auth server to verify the token is still valid.

Comment: not super familiar with azure functions, but I assume it's similar to AWS Lambdas, if so, why can't you use something (JWT based) to verify headers sent to it?

Comment: I have seen that approach.  Just not sure that 'validates' the token from the issue.  It just checks to see if it is there.  It could be expired/revoked.  But I am still researching.  Ideally you could leverage authentication middleware (like APIs use) and register the functions with the auth provider to enable the authentication and ensure tokens were good.  Thanks for the reply.